# Creating a binary fraction in python

Tags: python, binary

I am trying to create a binary number that contains a fraction. Something like this:

```
0b110.101
```

However, this gives a syntax error.

```
0b110
```

works fine though. How do you create a binary number that is not an integer?

Comment: You can't. Binary numbers are made up of only `1`s and `0`s.

Comment: Binary literals are only valid for integers, see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals

Comment: @Cristik, you can definitely have binary fractions. 110.101 is equal to 6.625 in base 10

Comment: `0b110 + 0b101 / (1<<3)`

Comment: I think Cristik was referring to Python's binary number *literals*.

Comment: `bin(6) == '0b110'` but `bin(6.625)` raises an exception: `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: @ikegami thanks that worked

Comment: @WilliamRoss the `0b` notation will convert the `0`s and `1`s to their actual memory representation. There's no dot in the binary world. The dot notation is more a mathematical representation. Real numbers (which also contain the fractional (rational) ones) are represented in other formats in memory, like [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: @Cristik, There's most definitely `.` in the binary world! The very page to which you linked uses it a dozen times!!!!

Comment: @Cristik I get what you mean that it's not possible to represent the dot in actual memory representation. I am wondering why it impossible to initialize with a binary fraction in Python specifically. As ikegami posted, it's pretty easy to use bitwise division to get what is needed in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How do you create a binary number that is not an integer?*

Binary is a *text* representation of a number. String are used to store text, so one would use something like the following:

```
"110.101"
```

But I think you misstated your question. You don't want the binary representation of a number, you want the number itself. 110.101<sub>2</sub> represents the number six and five eight. There are infinite ways to create create that number, including the following:

```
6 + 5/8
6.625
```

That said, I suspect you'd prefer to see the binary representation of the number in the source. Unfortunately, Python does not have decimal binary number literals. You could use

```
0b110101 / (1>>3)
bin_to_num("110.101")
```

Writing `bin_to_num` is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

You use the [Binary fractions](https://pypi.org/project/binary-fractions/) package.

This let's you convert binary-fraction strings into numbers and vice-versa
Example:

```
>>> from binary_fractions import Binary
>>> str(Binary(6.625))
'0b110.101'
>>> float(Binary("0b110.101"))
6.625
```

It has many more helper functions to manipulate binary strings such as: shift, add, fill, to_exponential, invert...

PS: Shameless plug, I'm the author of this package.